# 'Exception' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm decently new to Python, and I have a question over the implementation of a certain exception methodology. This is the code (shortened):

```
class OurException(Exception):
    """User defined Exception"""
....

def get_single_value(command: str, connect_string: str, logger: Logger = None, custom_exception: Exception = OurException) -> Tuple[int, str]:
....
    raise custom_exception("Errors in script\n\nexit .....")
```

The exception parameter that I defaulted to OurException cannot be raised this way. However, when I change the `custom_exception` in the last line to either `Exception` or `OurException`, the problem disappears.

In an OOP context, I'd say that as I have defined the parameter to be an Exception, and an Exception is callable that way, it is guaranteed to work. However, my python interpreter and IDE disagree (Pycharm, Python 3.7).

Something is not working the way I think it is working, and I'm interested what that is.

Comment: Are you passing in an argument that's overriding the default parameter when you call it?

Comment: `OurException` doesn't have type `Exception`.

Comment: in the case of a class it is not a parameter per se. It is super class from which this class is inheriting

Comment: `Exception` is the (super)type of an *instance* of `OurException`, not of the class.

Comment: To add my 2 cents to it. Having the caller pass the exception as an argument is a very weird scenario you have. If the caller is passing the exception class he must be expecting it in same way, so its not exactly an exception in the literal meaning.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I am trying to untangle code that was inside a monolithic script. This is the first idea I have moving one of the functions out of the monolith. The script used an exception that was custom defined in this way. I'm not very well versed in API design, and I had the idea to let the caller pass the exception it expects to be thrown. I could drop the exception type parameter and force raise the exception that my module is implementing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If `custom_exception` is supposed to be a *subclass* of `Exception`, you need to use the type hint `Type[Exception]`, not `Exception` itself. Otherwise, the type hint specifies that an *instance* of `Exception` is expected, and in general an instance of `Exception` is *not* callable.

```
from typing import Type


def get_single_value(command: str,
                     connect_string: str,
                     logger: Logger = None,
                     custom_exception: Type[Exception] = OurException) -> Tuple[int, str]:
    ....
    raise custom_exception("Errors in script\n\nexit .....")
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. That means that type hinting for Python differs from parameter type definitions of other languages, in that superclasses and subclasses are not checked for type hint validity.

Comment: I'm not aware of *any* language where a class would serve as the type for both an instance of the class and a subclass of the class.